# CSS dynamic horizontal navigation menu to fill up specific width (table behavior)

Tags: html, css, menu, html-table, navigation

I need to create a horizontal navigation menu with a changing number of items (this is important - I can't hard-code widths into the CSS and I don't want to calculate them with JS) that fill up to a certain width, let's say 800px.

With tables, [image]

```
<table width="800" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>Five Seven</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
table td {
      padding: 5px 0;
      margin: 0;
      background: #fdd;
      border: 1px solid #f00;
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Note that longer items take up more space and I can add items into the HTML without changing anything in CSS and the menu items shrink to accommodate additional items - the whole menu never being shorter or longer than 800px.

As a menu isn't a semantically correct use of a table, can this be done with say a  list and pure CSS?

Comment: I can think of a few "almosts" but not a 100% solution.  Maybe something with `display:table-cell`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [browsers that support the table display](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) CSS rules, yes:

```
<style>
  nav {display:table; width:800px; background:yellow}
  ul {display:table-row; }
  li {display:table-cell; border:1px solid red}
</style>

<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five Seven</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Basically, you'd have to build a token table. In action: http://jsbin.com/urisa4

Otherwise: no, not if you can't compromise your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Same solution as the person before you, but it doesn't work in IE7, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container { width: 800px ; border: 1px dashed #333; }
#container div { width: inherit; display: table-cell; background: #ccc}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
    <div>Something</div>
</div>
```

That way it fills up what you want, but can grow to a lot of items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Similar solution to those before you. Two problems: 1. (minor) all items have equal width, and 2. (major) IE7 doesn't support display: table-cell, so it doesn't work

Comment: That's pretty close, yes, but the inner div could use white-space:nowrap or else the line wraps if it becomes to wide.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this with CSS is to hard-code the `width` of the `li` elements (assuming you'd be using the following structure):

```
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five Seven</li>
  </ul>

ul {
    width: 80%; /* or whatever */
}

ul li {
    width: 16%;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xfRnd/).

This leaves, potentially, an 'unused' 10% (to be used for `margin` or additional `padding`).

At some point in the future [css calculations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) might be able to perform this more fluidly.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't know the number of menu items (e.g. the number of items is different for each section of the site) and each item has a different width based on the text length.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but i don´t think you want some think like this :)

```
<div class="master">
    <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>aölsdkfaösdlfk</li>
        <li>yeah baby</li>
        <li>hi</li>
    </ul>
</div>

.master {
   width:800px;
   background-color:black;
   height:100px;
   color:white;
    display:table;
}
table {
 width:100%;   
}

ul {
 display:table-row;  
 width:100%; 
}
li {
 display:table-cell;  
 width:auto; 
 margin:1px;
 border:1px solid white;
 background-color:red;
 text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UnNyS/

Comment: This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but breaks down in IE :(

Comment: you could look into the ie specs what classes they apply to the elements. Here I´m just copying the table classes...

Comment: IE7 doesn't support display: table at all, as the person after you pointed out.